# Are there non-brittle silicon-based alloys?

Tags: metal, metallurgy, alloy

Requirements:

- Silicon part is greater than 50%
- Has plasticity comparable to iron.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Mentioning *why* you want such an alloy  may help a potential answerer. Also, even though metallurgy isn't my area of expertise...if an alloy with a 50%+ silicon content isn't brittle, then I don't know *what* it is ;)

Comment: Yes, please elaborate on the use case. There are many silicides with >50 at.% Si, and I'm not going to sift through them all looking for mechanical property info...

Answer (score 4):

The only alloys I can think of where silicon would be present in that high a quantity would be ferrosilicon, silumin (where you very rarely get 50% Si), and things like silicon-germanium which are usually used as semiconductors for very small scale applications. Otherwise, you're looking at ceramics like silicon carbide.

All of those materials tend to be very brittle on a macro scale: on a nano scale, some ceramics show ductility. I'd be very surprised if you can find anything that matches your criteria though.